# Why is extended alignment implementation defined in std::aligned_storage

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, memory-alignment

Why is support for extended alignment implementation-defined in `std::aligned_storage_t`? It should be pretty easy to specify an implementation that uses `alignas()` on the appropriately sized buffer internally?

Comment: `alignas` has implementation-defined restrictions on its operand value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All support for extended alignment is [implementation defined](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.align#3):

> It is implementation-defined whether any extended alignments are supported **and the contexts in which they are supported**.

Emphasis added.

An implementation is free to support extended alignments in some places and not others. It might be OK to create a heap object with extended alignment, but not a stack object (or as a subobject of a stack variable). `aligned_storage` is simply another context.

---

> why [extended alignment] is implementation defined in some contexts where it should be well-defined (such as stack memory)?

Consider the implementation burden of heap allocation vs. stack allocation.

With heap allocation, what does a compiler need to do to make `new OverAlignedType` work? Pre-C++17? It requires *nothing*. Either `::operator new` will just so happen to allocate storage suitable for that alignment or undefined behavior results. The compiler has zero control over that. Same goes for placement-`new`; in that case, it's up to the user to align it properly.

C++17 added aligned forms of `operator new`. But even then, the only difference is which version of the function gets called. That's pretty trivial to for a compiler to implement.

Now consider stack allocation. I create a variable of type `OverAlignedType`. OK, so how does that get implemented? Obviously, the compiler looks at where the stack offset will be at that point in the function, based on the prior allocations on the stack. Then it-

*Wrong!* Why? Because the alignment of the actual address for where the stack *started* in that function call may not be appropriate for that type. Remember: for any given function invocation, the stack address will be based on whatever the current call graph is. If your `OverAlignedType` requires a 32-byte alignment, and the ABI only requires 16-byte alignment for the beginning of the stack, it is very possible that sometimes, the user happens to call it when the stack will be at a 32-byte boundary, and sometimes just 16-byte.

So what do you do? Well, you have to execute some *runtime code* in order to look at the actual stack address and align it where needed. Note that this turns a static, compile-time offset into a dynamic one. This may also affect the placement of every stack object in that function.

Or you can just forbid the user from using over-aligned types on the stack.

Comment: I see, didn't know that, thanks. Do you know why alignas is implementation defined in some contexts where it should be well-defined (such as stack memory)?

Comment: @Curious: `alignas` is not implementation-dependent. It is the use of *extended alignments* which is implementation dependent. As for why, consider how much work a compiler would have to do to implement extended alignment on stack variables compared to the heap.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like this is easier to implement on the stack as compared to the heap? Where there are API issues bleeding through the implementation of the standard library, etc? (for example, allocators using malloc would have to pass alignment information to the malloc backend from instantiation)

Comment: Thanks, last question - is there a way that you know of to check for compatibility of extended-alignment allocation on the stack?

Comment: @Curious: It's "implementation-defined". That means the implementation *must* document the behavior somewhere. That's the difference between "implementation defined" and "unspecified".

Comment: Could you give an example maybe so I could follow it? Or is that for another question?

Comment: @Curious: An example of what?

Comment: An example of an implementation’s documentation regarding extended alignment support for on-stack objects.